# Powershell handle variable with special character (open bracket)

Tags: powershell, variables, character, argumentexception

I have a script where two variables are compared, it can happen that a variable contains open brackets without closing, like in the example. Then a System.ArgumentException occur: "...not enough closing brackets.."

```
$test1="Testtext"
$test2="Testtext (3x(2x0,25"
if(!($test1 -match $test2)){ "test"}
```

how can i deal with it?

Comment: The `-match` operator is expecting the right-hand operand (e.g. `$test2`) to be a regular expression.  In your case you are supplying an invalid RegEx.  Try comparing with`-eq` instead: `if(!($test1 -eq $test2)){ "test"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-match` performs *regular expression* matching - use [`Regex.Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape) to automatically escape any escapable sequence in a verbatim pattern string:

```
$text = 'Text with (parens)'
$pattern = '(par'

if($text -match [regex]::Escape($pattern)){
  "It worked!"
}
```